# The method onApplicationEvent is not executed at the start in the Test

Tags: java, spring

This is the part of the code of the `@Component` in my Spring MVC application:

```
@Component
public class CacheServiceImpl implements CacheService, ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger( CacheServiceImpl.class );

    private Jedis JEDIS;

    @Value("${redis.host.url}")
    String redishost;

    @Value("${redis.host.port}")
    int redisport;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info("Starting application...");
        JEDIS = new Jedis(this.redishost,this.redisport);
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

When I run application, the method `onApplicationEvent` is executed at the start (so, it's ok). However, when I run the test, then it looks like the method `onApplicationEvent` is not executed, because `JEDIS` is equal to `null`.

This is the code of the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class CacheServiceImplTest {

    private CacheServiceImpl cacheService;
    private List<UD> listUD;

    @Test
    public void updateCache() throws Exception
    {
        cacheService.updateCache(listUD);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        cacheService = new CacheServiceImpl();
        List<String> stringData = readStreamOfLinesUsingFiles();
        listUD = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String rs : stringData)
        {
            UD ud = new UD(rs);
            listUD.add(ud);
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    private List<String> readStreamOfLinesUsingFiles() throws IOException
    {
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("MYFILE.txt"));
        List<String> result = lines.collect(Collectors.toList());
        lines.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class CacheServiceImplTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        // this bean will be injected into the OrderServiceTest class
        @Bean
        public CacheServiceImpl cacheService() {
            CacheServiceImpl cacheService = new CacheServiceImpl();
            return cacheService;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private CacheServiceImpl cacheService;
}
```

Comment: And why should it? What do you think `new CacheServiceImpl()`.. How is Spring involved in that... How do you expect spring to call a method on an class instance it doesn't know?

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks. Could you please recommend the proper way to create a test?

Comment: let spring create the instance and inject it into your testcase.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Do you mean I should delete the line `cacheService = new CacheServiceImpl();` and add some extra-code to allow Spring to create the instance?

Comment: Read the testing chapter of the reference guide. Use `@ContextConfiguration` to specify your configuration class and use `@Autowired` to get the `CacheServiceImpl` instance. Or redesign your `CacheServiceImpl` so that you can easily construct it, like injecting the `Jedis` instance into the bean using a constructor and let Spring (or the test) create the Jedis instance and manage it for you. No callback methods needed then.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Please check my update. I tried to inject the Jedis instance using `@Autowired`, but it cannot see variables `redishost` and `redisport`.

Comment: No you haven't you are constructing one yourself... Seems you seem to lack basic knowledge about dependency injection and how to model things.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Ok, I think I figured it out in my last Update. The only issue now is related to the parameters of Jedis. If I use `String redishost="localhost"; int redisport=6379;` in the `CacheserviceImpl`, then everything works. But if I want to use `@Value("${redis.host.port}")`, then it cannot inject the values.

Comment: You shouldn't create the `Jedis` instance in your class, you should inject the `Jedis` instance... And in your configuration create the `Jedis` instance. That way you can do whatever you want in your testcase and also have the ability to share a single `Jedis` instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Ah, ok, I understand. Now it works fine, Thanks.